# Android Room - Split @Entity into Key and DataObject

Tags: android, database, android-room

The last few days I played around with Android and Jetpack. I used Room for storing my data on a local DB. By now all is running fine, but I want to simplify and reorder my code.

So I am wondering if it is possible to split the @Entity class for my Tables into a KEY class (including all key values) and a DO class (including non key values)!?

For information: I used this method for a personal JAVA project and I am thinking it is a really nice way to keep everything structured and it is easier to keep an overview!

Thanks!!

Comment: You could try using `@Embedded` on a `@PrimaryKey` field. I have not tried this and I do not know if it is supported, but it is the only way I can think of that would give you what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is possible, you just need to declare your key class, Do class then define a TypeConverter for each of them. a TypeConverter defines how complex objects are stored in database (for instance data objects).
Please refer to this documentation article: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data